# programmatically remove entry from windows error log

Tags: windows, wmi

I need to programmatically remove a single entry from the Windows event log. I think it's likely that I could accomplish this through WMI (which would be ideal, but certainly not necessary), but am not sure how to do so.

Comment: By design, there is no way to remove individual entries from the event log.  You can only erase the entire log.

Comment: Out of curiousity, **why** would you want to remove a single entry?  What do you want to hide?

Comment: I'm not trying to _hide_ anything. I have software that checks the event log to detect a "duplicate IP address detected" error, but if I dont remove it from the log then my code will complain about it _every_ time thereafter until the entry is removed. I suppose an alternate solution would be to compare the entry to the last boot time and see if lastBootTime > timeOfError then we have an issue, else ignore it and move on.